# Performance impact of many small react.CreateElement on the same document?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I tried to google this, but all I got was recipes to make react apps faster, or recipes on how to have multiple apps on the same page, but nothing about the relative performace of having one vs multiple/many react.createElement on the same page...

Have a legacy app built on zend/twig, and we are (very slowly) moving it to react. So far we have mostly moved things one view at a time, but we are considering making smaller components to be used across the site, like making a table header component and replace all table headers. So if the table had 30 headers, it would be 30 react.CreateElement. Is that theoretically an ok idea or will it have in any case a big performance impact?

Any insight would be very much appreciated,
Gioia

Comment: I think you may need to test it out and decide yourself. Under the hood, React is calling `createElement` constantly for every element anyway when you use JSX, see [react without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). I think the issue that you will run into more with is that if these are all different mount points, they likely won't share a reactive dep tree and can't also share context. Can you show an example of what you want to try doing to make it clearer?

Comment: @zero298 From your answer would seem that theoretically at least it shouldn't have a big impact, but yeah, I will test it out and know for sure :)